# Pandas : how to select index/row label in dataframe that matches a condition

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe that looks like this

```
        fail    success
aa      1       0
ab      1       0
aback   0       1
abandon 3       1
abate   0       1
abc     1       0
```

where "fail" and "success" are the names of the columns and "aa", "ab", "aback", etc. are the labels of the rows.
The table contains the number of times a word ("ab", "aback", etc.) appears in a group of texts (2 groups : "fail" and "success").

Is there a way to associate each row label with a column name based on wether the word is unique in one of the groups ?

The output should look something like this :

```
{'fail' : [("aa",1),("ab",1),("abc",1)], 'success' : [("aback",1),("abate",1)]}
```

Thank you !

Answer (score 3):

You can do this with a `dict` comprehension:

```
{col: list(df.loc[(df[col] > 0) & (df.drop(columns=col) == 0).all(axis=1), col].iteritems())
 for col in df.columns}
```

Output:

```
{'fail': [('aa', 1), ('ab', 1), ('abc', 1)],
 'success': [('aback', 1), ('abate', 1)]}
```

This will work even  if you have more than two columns. Effectively, what it does is, for each column, get the index-value pairs which satisfy the following two conditions:

1. The value is more than 0 for that index in that column
2. The value is 0 for all other indices in that column

If you assume that there are no rows for which all values are nonzero, then you can drop the first condition, which gives this:

```
{col: list(df.loc[(df.drop(columns=col) == 0).all(axis=1), col].iteritems())
 for col in df.columns}
```

Comment: I like this.  You can probably remove the `(df[col] > 0) &` part, if the assumption is that each row will have at least one non-zero column (which given the framing of the question is probably reasonable).  Also, `for col in df.columns` is the same as `for col in df`.

Comment: @JohnZwinck True, nice observation.

Answer (score 0):

Let's do the "success" half first:

```
df.success[df.fail==0]
```

This gives you the values of success where fail was zero:

```
aback    1
abate    1
```

If you really need a list-of-lists, do this:

```
df.success[df.fail==0].reset_index().values.tolist()
```

Now you have:

```
[['aback', 1], ['abate', 1]]
```

Alternatively, for a list of tuples as in your example output:

```
s = df.success[df.fail==0]
list(zip(s.index, s))
```

Swap success and fail for the other half of the result, and you're done.

Answer (score 0):

Using pandas `nunique`, with `stack` , then `groupby` get the `dict` by `to_dict`

```
df[df.ne(0).nunique(1).ne(1)].\
    replace(0,np.nan).\
      stack().\
          reset_index(0).apply(tuple,1).\
              groupby(level=0).apply(list).to_dict()
Out[497]: 
{'fail': [('aa', 1.0), ('ab', 1.0), ('abc', 1.0)],
 'success': [('aback', 1.0), ('abate', 1.0)]}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

```
new_dict = {}
new_dict['fail'] = df[((df['fail']==1)&(df['success']==0))]['fail'].reset_index().values.tolist()
new_dict['success'] = df[((df['fail']==0)&(df['success']==1))]['success'].reset_index().values.tolist()
```

Output:

```
{'fail': [['aa', 1], ['ab', 1], ['abc', 1]], 'success': [['aback', 1], ['abate', 1]]}
```